# Pentaho convert string into rows

Tags: string, rows, pentaho

my source file is like below

col1, col2
abc, [""file11123/.avro"",""file123231223223/.avro"",""file...n.avro"]

o/P I a looking for

abc file11123.avro
abc file123231223223.avro
abc file...n.avro

removing the special characters[""/] then convert string into rows, file names to load into table.

Comment: some how my question was covered to one line. - the o/p hearder1 should come n number to times as the other string split into rows, it will have the s3bucket name, header 2 will be the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two steps:

- *Replace in string* step: to clean the special characters in col2. Using a Regexp, you search this formula to clean all in one step: [[|]|"|/], leaving the Replace with field null to just eliminate them. Generate a new column with the cleaned fields
- *Split field to rows* step: You use the commas to split the new column in rows each time you find a comma.

[image]